# Query on Getters and Setters generated through Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

When I use the "**Generate Getter and Setter**" from eclipse on the below

private String **c**ode - I get the below generated

```
public void setCode(String code) {
    **this**.code = code;
}
```

private String **S**tudy - I get the below generated but why do I not see "this.Study = study"

```
public void setStudy(String study) {
    Study = study;
```

Why does Eclipse do this ? The only difference is the first letter which is in CAPS

Not that it is a matter of concern but I would still like to know the reason behind it

Comment: `Study` and `study` aren't the same name, so there's no reason to add a redundant `this` keyword.

Comment: Eclipse generates the name of the variable according to the java naming conventions which say that a variable name starts with a lower case letter, As it is another name than the member variable the `this` keyword is not needed, as _azurefrog_ already mentioned.